# Applying scrolling physics to an app

Tags: physics

I believe this is a fairly simple question but I have no idea where to start.

I'm trying to implement a feature where an entity (such as an image) can be flicked across the screen such that it decelerates over time based on an initial speed (non-zero) and coefficient of friction.

In other words, given an initial velocity and constant friction, how can I programmtically  determine **where** an object will be at time **t**??

Feel free reply using pseudo-code or any programming language you're comfortable with.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is

```
s = u*t + 0.5*a*t*t
```

where,

```
s is displacement (i.e. position)
u is the initial speed (can be zero too actually)
a is the acceleration (if you want deceleration use a negative value instead)
t is the time elapsed
```

To account for friction your `a` will be (on a horizontal surface)

```
a = -μg
```

where,

```
μ is the coefficient of friction
g is gravitational acceleration
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to take friction into consideration. EDIT: Oops, sorry I didn't see your next edit.